# Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "0": syntax error

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I simply want to create a table with one column and add some values to it but I get two errors. One is if I uncomment db.close(); the handle closes too quick and the other is `Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "0": syntax error` below is the code.

```
var file = "DB.sqlite3";
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(file);

if(!fs.existsSync(file)) fs.openSync(file, "w");

db.serialize(function() {        
    db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (id INTEGER)`);
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        db.run(`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM players WHERE id=${i})`, function(error, row) {
            if (row === undefined) 
                db.run(`INSERT INTO players (id) VALUES (?)`,i);
            if(error) console.log(error);
        });
    }
});
//db.close();    //if I uncomment I get that the handle has closed
```

Comment: Okay I am an idiot and I simply hadn't closed the bracket, ignore the previous error, and focus only on the db close

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as I am only a beginner but I think your dbclose needs to go inside the last bracket like this:

```
var file = "DB.sqlite3";
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(file);

if(!fs.existsSync(file)) fs.openSync(file, "w");

db.serialize(function() {        
    db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (id INTEGER)`);
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        db.run(`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM players WHERE id=${i})`, function(error, row) {
            if (row === undefined) 
                db.run(`INSERT INTO players (id) VALUES (?)`,i);
            if(error) console.log(error);
        });
    }
db.close();
});
```